# Django multiple relations in one model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have been trying to create a model that could represent the form as it is, tried creating an `EntryForm` model which is linked to `EntryFormTable` where then each column in the table is a model class all linked to the table, but then this proved to be a long way and one that doesn't even work, maybe there's a short or even a working method to represent this in django models,
[image: entry form]

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to model the "things" as they are in real life, and not as they would appear on the screen. So don't create a model called `EntryForm`, `EntryFormTable` or `EntryFormColumn`, but rather name them what they are. Example based on your image:

```
class CoveredWorkSet(Model):
    school: CharField()
    learning_area: CharField()
    teacher: ForeignKey(Teacher)  # or just CharField if you don't have them in your database
    role:
    grade: CharField()


class CoveredWork(Model):
    covered_work_set = ForeignKey(CoveredWorkSet, related_name='records')
    date = DateField()
    lesson = CharField()
    work_done = BooleanField()
    reflection = TextField()


class Signature(Model):
    """
    Represents a signature on either a CoveredWork record or a complete CoveredWorkSet
    """

    ROLE_CHOICES = [
        ('subject', 'Subject teacher'),
        ('class', 'Class teacher'),
        ('head', 'Head teacher'),
    ]

    teacher = ForeignKey(Teacher, related_name='signatures')
    role = CharField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES)
    covered_work_set = ForeignKey(CoveredWorkSet, null=True)
    covered_work = ForeignKey(CoveredWor, null=True)
    date = DateTimeField()
    signature = ImageField()
```